# How can I find sum of highlighted cells?

Tags: excel

I've just been asked an Excel question at work, but I'm not an Excel person, I rarely use it.

Is it possible to do a `SUM()` of the highlighted boxes?

[image: Excel Image]

I've looked online but only found plugins or VBA scripts.

As for a VBA Script solution, this is what I have:

```
Function SUMCLR(rColor As Range, rRange As Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult
    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = WorksheetFunction.SUM(rCell, vResult)
        End If
    Next rCell
    SUMCLR = vResult
End Function
```

It works but if there is an inbuilt function, that'd be great.

Comment: how are the highlighted boxes being highlighted?

Comment: Basically just using a background colour.

Comment: ok - so it's not automatic, someone is going through and highlighting them manually. (Yuck!)

Comment: If it was me, I'd have a different system altogether. Also turns out that the above macro does not auto update. But it is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in excel 2007 or later you could sort that column by colour, and sum up only the coloured boxes (which will now all be grouped together at the top or bottom). Anything else would mean;

1. Getting people to make a mark next to the number that is "interesting"
2. Require vba - as per your post.

If the colours have been created using conditional formatting (check by selecting the home tab, and conditional formatting while one of the highlighted cells are selected) then you can use the same formula and sumproduct or similar to calculate the sum.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid the solution may require VBA. It's no problem, it'll have to do, would have been nice if it was inbuilt though.